# Birational maps and Picard groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are curves, and suppose $f: Y \to X$ is a birational map.  If $f$ is bijective on geometric points, what can be said about the induced map on the Picard groups $Pic(X) \to Pic(Y)$ by taking pullbacks?  I think this is always surjective, but don't know how to prove.  When is this map an isomorphism?

What is known in the case of higher dimensional schemes?

Comment: If you take pullbacks, the map on Picard groups goes the other way round.

Comment: In higher dimensional schemes, the map *the other way around* (ie, the pullback map) is definitely not surjective.  For example, blowing up a point on the plane $\pi : Y \to X = \mathbb{A}^2$ creates a new $P^1$ which isn't the pull back of any divisor on $X$.  See for example Hartshorne, Chapter 5, Prop 3.2.  

Comment: ... and it cannot be surjective by dimension reasons


Comment: What is your definition of "curve"?  Are "curves" allowed to be non-reduced?  Re higher dimensions, certainly the pullback map is not always a surjection, e.g., a minimal desingularization of the projective cone over a smooth plane curve of degree > 2.

Comment: Thanks for the correction.  Curves are allowed to be non-reduced; but is there a result for reduced curves?  

Answer (score 6):

For reduced curves over algebraically closed fields, this is indeed true even without the assumption on bijectivity of points. This is because, given any line bundle on $Y$, it can be represented as a Cartier divisor whose support avoids any given finite set of points. So choosing all the singular points (which are finite since the curve is reduced) and the finitely many points where the map is not an isomorphism, we see that the image of the divisor is a Cartier divisor on $X$ whose pull back is clearly the same divisor that we started with.